# Problem book on functors and category theory?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, functors

I am trying to find a book I saw many years ago at a university library. Unfortunately, I remember so little of the book that I haven't been able to effectively search. What I do recall is that:

- the book was like a problem book on functors and category theory
- the first few pages, iirc, had a dialogue between 2 people
- the hardcover I saw had a blue (green?) cover, and probably had around 200 pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780817641863

[image]
You're welcome! (this is added just to reach 30 characters)

Comment: OMG, I think this was it! Thank you so much!